# Metrics in Row To Columns (and Dates from column to Rows)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Currently I have two reports and they are in different format and was hoping to use macro or formulas to convert either one of the reports to the same format as the other so as to merge the two reports together.

As the two reports provide different metrics but based on the same **name** and **date** (as segments). I'm was wondering if there's a way to do it other than manually pivot table each of the date range and manually convert everything.

Below is the example, I would like to convert the first report which has metrics (Food A, B and C) arranged in rows while Date (`16-Sep-2016` and `25-Sep-2016`) arranged in Columns to the other way round as shown in the picture of the table below.

Example Picture:

[image]

Hope to hear from anyone soon!

Thank you :)

Comment: Just wondering if the first table always had the same number of names and exactly the same names per food (i.e. 4 A's, 4 B's and 4 C's)? Then you might be able to do it with a fairly simple formula.

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe For the actual report, there's a huge variant in the "names", "date" and "food" so I have been encountering problems like runtime error overflow etc. Haha

Answer (score 1):

It's far from optimal, just a quick solution, but it does the job. It converts the upper table in your picture into the other one. Your original table must be on the first sheet, and you need an empty second sheet before you run the macro:

```
Sub TableChanger()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"

    i = 2
    n = 2
    While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        j = 3
        While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).Value And Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).Value <> ""
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        If Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).Value = "" Then
            Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend

    i = 3
    While Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value <> ""
        j = 2
        While Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""

            k = 3
            While Sheets(2).Cells(1, k).Value <> Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value
                k = k + 1
            Wend

            n = 2
            While (Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value <> Sheets(2).Cells(n, 1).Value Or Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value <> Sheets(2).Cells(n, 2).Value) And Sheets(2).Cells(n, 1) <> ""
                n = n + 1
            Wend

            Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, k).Value
            If Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then Sheets(2).Cells(j, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(n, k).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(j, i).Value

            j = j + 1
        Wend
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tretom, just curious if it is dynamic, like for example if there's more names other than those 3 mentioned, and more food and date also, would  it be possible?

Comment: Oh yes and also if there's a runtime overflow error how should i go around this? haha thank you!

Comment: @Ka Chee Ho: I've tested it only with a few cases. Added extra columns and rows, and for me it worked.
Overflow error: OK, I didn't implement any error handling. You might make a search on the `On Error`possibilities in VBA

Comment: @Ka Chee Ho: Overflow error:
change the lines:
`Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim n As Integer`
to the following:
`Dim i As Double, j As Double, k As Double
    Dim n As Double`